# McAfee Endpoint Security for Linux Threat Prevention cannot schedule ODS-Tasks

Tags: linux, anti-virus, cronjob

McAfee Endpoint Security for Linux Threat Prevention, Version : 10.5.4.106

We are working on a Linux server with a pre-installed McAfee. The regular ODS-Scanning has been really annoyed us. So we've tried to configure it to auto-exceute scanning only on every Sunday.

We've found two related ODS-Tasks ("ENS10_ODS_WEEKLY" and "ENS10_ODS_DAILY") from the log-directory "/opt/isec/ens/threatprevention/var/odsreport". and then we've tried to find their task-Indexes using "/opt/isec/ens/threatprevention/bin/isecav --listtasks". But these two don't exist in the return: there are just Index1: quick scan and Index2: full scan.

We could have used "/opt/isec/ens/threatprevention/bin/isecav --scheduletask --index" to setup that two tasks as expected.